# does a thread start causes a memory barrier (shared variables will be persisted in memory)?

Tags: java, multithreading

I wonder if invoking a thread start has the safe effect of updating a volatile or after acquiring a lock?

Answer (score 2):

to quote http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility

> - A call to start on a thread happens-before any action in the started thread.

which along with the other effects listed:

> - An unlock (synchronized block or method exit) of a monitor
>   happens-before every subsequent lock (synchronized block or method
>   entry) of that same monitor. And because the happens-before relation
>   is transitive, all actions of a thread prior to unlocking
>   happen-before all actions subsequent to any thread locking that
>   monitor.
> - A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent
>   read of that same field. Writes and reads of volatile fields have
>   similar memory consistency effects as entering and exiting monitors,
>   but do not entail mutual exclusion locking.

so yes it has the same effects

Answer (score 1):

The newly started thread will act as a memory barrier for that particular thread.

All other threads will have to synchronize the access ( by entering `synchronized` block or acquiring a lock ) to see the updated non-final non-volatile variables.